# Why the WDT ISR is not executing?

Tags: c, embedded, avr-gcc

```
    void watchdog_disable()
{
    cli();      // disable global interrupt
    MCUSR &= ~(1<<WDRF);    // clear the Watchdog System Reset Flag (WDRF)
    WDTCSR |= (1<<WDCE) | (1<<WDE); // In the same operation, write a logic one to WDCE & WDE
    WDTCSR = 0x00;  // Within the next four clock cycles, write the WDTCSR.WDE and Watchdog prescaler bits group
                    // (WDTCSR.WDP) as desired, but with the WDTCSR.WDCE cleared. This must be done in one operation.
}

// RV8A1, Date: 01-Jun-2022, Enable watchdog timer for system reset
void watchdog_enable()
{
    cli();      // disable global interrupt
    WDTCSR |= (1<<WDCE) | (1<<WDE); // In the same operation, write a logic one to WDCE & WDE
    WDTCSR = 0x08;  // Within the next four clock cycles, write the WDTCSR.WDE and Watchdog prescaler bits group
                    // (WDTCSR.WDP) as desired, but with the WDTCSR.WDCE cleared. This must be done in one operation.
                    // WDE = 1, WDIE = 0, WDP[2:0] = 000; System Reset Mode Enabled;
    sei();
}

// RV8A1, Date: 01-Jun-2022, Enable watchdog timer in Interrupt mode
void watchdog_interrupt_enable()
{
    cli();      // disable global interrupt
    WDTCSR |= (1<<WDCE) | (1<<WDE); // In the same operation, write a logic one to WDCE & WDE
    WDTCSR = 0x61;  // Within the next four clock cycles, write the WDTCSR.WDE and Watchdog prescaler bits group
                    // (WDTCSR.WDP) as desired, but with the WDTCSR.WDCE cleared. This must be done in one operation.
                    // WDE = 0, WDIE = 1, WDP[3:0] = 1001; Interrupt Mode Enabled;
    sei();
}


//*******************************************************************************

////////////////////////////main begin////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
char numtochar ( int charrxvd)
{
    char ch='x';
    switch (charrxvd)
    {
        case 0 : ch = '0';
        break;
        case 1 : ch = '1';
        break
        case 2 : ch = '2';
        break;
        case 3 : ch = '3';
        break;
        case 4 : ch = '4';
        break;
        case 5 : ch = '5';
        break;
        case 6 : ch = '6';
        break;
        case 7 : ch = '7';
        break;
        case 8 : ch = '8';
        break;
        case 9 : ch = '9';
        break;      
    }
     return ch;
}
void sendnumber(unsigned int num)
{
    cpsrvrflg = 0;
    Send2esp8266("AT+CIPSERVER=0\r\n");
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        _delay_ms(250);
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    Send2esp8266("AT+CIPMUX=0\r\n");  // single
    for(i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
        _delay_ms(250);
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    
    
    //Send2esp8266("AT+CIPSTART=\"UDP\",\"192.168.42.14\",5001\r\n");   
    Send2esp8266("AT+CIPSTART=\"UDP\",\"192.168.42.1\", 5002\r\n");
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        _delay_ms(250);
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    Send2esp8266("AT+CIPMODE=1\r\n"); //
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        _delay_ms(250);
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    Send2esp8266("AT+CIPSEND\r\n"); // 7 characters
    for(i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
        _delay_ms(250);
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    Send2esp8266("WDT FREQ = ");
    int x;
    while((num/10.0) != 0)
    {
        x=num%10;
        uart_transmit(numtochar(x));
        num=num/10;
    }
    
    Send2esp8266("+++");
            
    for(i=0; i<15; i++)
    {
        _delay_ms(250);
    }
    Send2esp8266("AT+CIPCLOSE\r\n");
    
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        _delay_ms(250);
    }
    
    Send2esp8266("AT+CIPMODE=0\r\n"); //transparent mode off
    for(i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
        _delay_ms(250);
    }



}



// timer freq = 11059200hz; for 1 tick = 1/11059200 sec =5.79usec
// total tick =50; tcnt0 start 255-50=205 = 0xCD; timer freq = 11059200/50 = 221184hz
float wdttimeout=0;int wdtisr=0;
void timer1_init()
{
    TCNT1=0xFFCD;//0x80 org//dec 128
    TIMSK1=0x01;
    TCCR1A &= ~(1<<WGM10); // RV09_H, Date: 05-May-2022, set Normal mode operation
    TCCR1A &= ~(1<<WGM11);
    TCCR1B &= ~(1<<WGM13);
    TCCR1B &= ~(1<<WGM12);
    TCCR1B |= (1<<CS10); //no prescalar; freq = fosc=11059200hz
}

void timer1_stop()
{
    TCCR1B = 0x00;
    TIMSK1 = 0x00;

}
ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect)
{
  //uart_transmit(timeoutsec);
    TCNT1=0xFFCD;
    wdttimeout++;
 //tmrflag=1;
 //uart_transmit(timeoutsec);
 //uart_transmit('\n');
}

float trackwdt()
{
    wdttimeout=0;wdtisr=0;
    int num=0;
    timer1_init();
    watchdog_interrupt_enable();
    while(wdtisr==0);
    watchdog_disable();   // RV8A1, 01-Jun-2022, watchdog disable
    num = (int)(wdttimeout*(50/11059200))*1000; // time in ms
    return(wdttimeout);
}

ISR(WDT_vect)
{
    timer1_stop();
    wdtisr=1;
}
void main()
{
  trackwdt();
}
```

The above code is written to measure the watchdog timer frequency using the timer1. timer1 is configured to count at 221khz, then the counted value is multiplied by the overflow period of timer1 to get the timer duration of WDT interrupt.

But the code is hung at while no interrupt are generated by the watchdog timer.

Why the code is hanging?

Comment: `volatile int wdtisr = 0;`

Comment: Sorry, Is that the problem to hang? @Juraj

Comment: `wdtisr` should be declared volatile since it's value can change in the ISR context.  But that's not the only problem if the WDT ISR never executes.  Does the TIMER1 ISR execute?  Does it execute more than once and at the intended rate?  Do you need to clear the TIMER1 IRQ in the TIMER1 ISR?

Comment: `(int)(wdttimeout*(50/11059200))*1000;` is nonsense, this will always be replaced by zero by the compiler. You shouldn't be using floating point to begin with - precalculate the value outside your code then make a comment containing the equation and values that you used.